# Chrome clearing input type=number

Tags: html, google-chrome

In the latest release `"47.0.2526.73"` all my input `type="number"` are clearing every time that we try to type a float point number, `example : 1.1`

These inputs have a keyup event handler in jQuery to remove the leading zeros.

This code was working before the latest update.

**Is there a bug?**

-- UPDATE --

```
//Fix to leading zero decimals
$('input[type=number]').keyup(function (e) {
   if (!this.value && (e.keyCode == 190 || e.keyCode == 110)) {
      this.value = '0.';
   }
});
```

This is the code that is not longer working

Comment: Because that is not a valid number....

Comment: Can you show some code where this problem can be seen?

Answer (score 0):

Change the step so it don't use the default '1' and uses a float. It will allow you to use float numbers and not only integers.
Ex: '0.1'

Comment: And what happens if you set '0.0' instead of '0.'? (Note: I know that it will probably will make the input receive 0.01, but this is just for test sake, because with AngularJS I never had this problem, my days of JQuery are gone.)

Comment: It sets properly but the event has changed, I cannot access the input value, it is always empty

Answer (score 0):

Looks like chrome is no longer allowing you to read/set the input value for number types using the keyup event when it is in the middle of the decimal point typing.

This is when the user type just '.', you cannot get the value '1.' or set it the same way in the event.

What I did was change the logic to:

```
$('input[type=number]').keyup(function (e) {
   if (this.value) {
      if (this.value.charAt(0) == '.')
      {
         this.value = '0' + this.value;
      }
   }
});
```

This is the only way that I have found to fix typing a number without the leading zero in the input box